# c# .net - timestamp issue

Tags: c#, .net, timestamp

In the db, the field is showing the current time but in the UI I am not seeing the current time. If I run for the second time, it is showing the right time which is the current time. Y is this issue happening?

I have used DateTime now = DateTime.NOW;

It is giving the right time in the db but not in the UI for the first run.

Comment: What time is it showing, what time should it be showing, and how different are they? Have you ruled out issues with UTC conversion?

Answer (score 0):

The field is receiving a NULL value the first time is it processed which may mean you are trying to fill the field before the date-time.Now is stored into the now variable and used. You must store the value into the variable before it is used in order for the field to populate.

Consider doing a debug and then changing the order of when a variable is instantiated and when it is used.